# What happens if you are simultaneously modifying an array that you are looping through in node js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops

I'm new to node js and am just getting used to the asynchronous nature of the language...

I have a function that updates values in an array **A** every 60 seconds (grabs them from a database).

I also have a function that processes requests from users, and while processing these requests it uses values from **A** (and so I loop over **A**).

I'm wondering if this type of thing being asynchronous will crash my app?

For example if I'm in the middle of looping over **A** and grabbing values but at the same time, the 60 second timer hits and begins to update the values in **A**, can anything bad happen?

If so, do you have any design suggestions to avoid this?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: asynchronous does not mean multi threaded - so while you are synchronously looping through **A**, any "event" that would result in changes to **A** wont run until your synchronous code is complete

Comment: You would get much more specific and meaningful answers if you included specific code examples from your code.  Concurrency issues depend upon the exact code and cannot be determined solely from your textual descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends upon your exact code so no concrete answer can be provided without seeing and understanding your exact code.

Javascript in node.js is single threaded so if you are looping through an array with a synchronous mechanism such as `.forEach()` or a `for` loop, then any async calls you make will be initiated, but they cannot finish until after your current thread of execution (including the loop through the array) is completely done.  So, no async result can impact the array while you are still looping.

There are less conventional and async ways to iterate through the array.  If you were using one of those, we'd have to see your actual code to offer an opinion on whether you have any concurrency issues or not.

> For example if I'm in the middle of looping over A and grabbing values
>   but at the same time, the 60 second timer hits and begins to update
>   the values in A, can anything bad happen?

node.js is event-driven.  This means that when a timer is ready to fire, it inserts an event into the node.js event queue.  That event will not be processed until the current running Javascript is done and the node.js JS engine can then pull the next event out of the event queue.  So, a timer will not interrupt your current running Javascript, ever.

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter weird bugs from doing this. If you are in the middle of A and A gets much shorter, it will terminate the loop. For example suppose that A has 30 elements. While you are looping though, it gets changed to length 15 when you are on index 16. It would not continue looping. Another example. Suppose that A has length 2. When you finish the stuff for the first index, when you go to the second, the value of both indexes gets changed, then the first one would be reported as the old value, and the second one as the new value.